# Using Rijndael-128 with CBC mode in Java 8

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I am rewriting some PHP code in Java 8 where Rijndael-128 cipher (AES) is being used for encryption and decryption. The IV being used is 16 characters (128 bit) long, but the key being used is 18 characters (144 bit) long.

I have tried to write encryption method in Java using JCA and by explicitly using bouncycastle library, but for both I am getting error for key length. Is it possible to use 144 bit key in PHP? If yes, please suggest how the same can be used in Java. Please find the code used and error encountered mentioned below:

**php**

```php
$cipherText = bin2hex($this->mcryptVal($this->pkcs5_pad($plainText), $key, $iv));

private function mcryptVal($text, $key, $iv, $encrypt = true) {
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $result = ($encrypt) ? mcrypt_generic($td, $text) : mdecrypt_generic($td, $text);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);

        return $result;
    }

private function pkcs5_pad($text) {
        $blocksize = 16;
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);

        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }
```

**java**

```java
    String plainText = "Hello World";
    String key = ***; //144 bit (18 characters)
    String iv = ***; //128 bit
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
        new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(128)), new ZeroBytePadding());
    CipherParameters ivAndKey =
        new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key.getBytes()), iv.getBytes());
    cipher.init(true, ivAndKey);
    byte[] out = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(pkcs5Pad(plainText).getBytes().length)];
    int l1 = cipher.processBytes(pkcs5Pad(plainText).getBytes(), 0,
        pkcs5Pad(plainText).getBytes().length, out, 0);
    int l2 = cipher.doFinal(out, l1);
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[l1 + l2];
    for (int i = 0; i < l1 + l2; i++) {
      encrypted[i] = out[i];
    }
    String encryptedText = Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted);


public static String pkcs5Pad(String plainText) {
    int blockSize = 16;
    int pad = blockSize - (plainText.length() % blockSize);
    return plainText.concat(StringUtils.repeat((char) pad, pad));
  }
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/160/192/224/256 bits.
```

**PS** : code mentioned for Java is using bouncycastle, similar code using JCA lead to similar error for key length

Comment: `pkcs5_pad()` and `pkcs5Pad()` are missing. PHP extends the key implicitly to 24 bytes (AES-192) by padding with 0x00 bytes, Java does not, i.e. there it must be done explicitly. Furthermore BC supports PKCS#7 padding. And you can use `AESEngine`.

Comment: @Topaco , I have added the pkcs5_pad() and pkcd5Pad() to the post.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues to change in the Java code:

- Valid key sizes for AES are 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192) and 32 bytes (AES-256), i.e. 18 bytes is not a valid key size. The PHP code implicitly extends the 18 bytes key to the next valid AES key size, namely 24 bytes (i.e. AES-192), by padding with 0x00 values. The key extension must be done explicitly in the Java code. This is missing and is the reason for the exception.
- `pkcs5_pad()` in the PHP code implements PKCS#7 padding (sometimes historically called PKCS#5 padding in the Java world). On the Java side, no custom implementation is needed since BouncyCastle supports PKCS#7 padding. Note that when using the custom variant, the padding must be *completely* disabled. Also Zero padding must not be used, since the BouncyCastle variant, unlike the mcrypt variant, always pads (i.e. even if the last block is completely filled) and therefore both variants are not equivalent.
- Furthermore, the more specific `AESEngine` should be used instead of the `RijndaelEngine`. Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits for the key sizes 16, 24 and 32 bytes corresponds per defintionem to AES. This last point is not a bug, but should be implemented for efficiency reasons.

Thus, your Java implementation changes slightly to:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

...

byte[] plainText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] keyInvalid = "012345678901234567".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // 18 bytes key, no valid AES key size
byte[] key = new byte[24]; // next valid AES key size after 18 is 24 bytes (valid AES key sizes: 16, 24, 32 bytes)
System.arraycopy(keyInvalid, 0, key, 0, keyInvalid.length);
byte[] iv = "0123456789012345".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()), new PKCS7Padding());
CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
cipher.init(true, ivAndKey);
byte[] ciphertext = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(plainText.length)];
int length = cipher.processBytes(plainText, 0, plainText.length, ciphertext, 0);
cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, length);
String ciphertextHex = Hex.toHexString(ciphertext);

System.out.println(ciphertextHex); // 4e4d648e1af730b6c7571cbd033a43c478f423a958f70bdf5929418e978d3126a7f7bbbeaea06e6cf12e99b922918917
```

Note that the encryption performed here (AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding) is also possible under Java 8 using on-board means (i.e. via SunJCE provider), i.e. BouncyCastle is not actually necessary.

---

Test:

The PHP code returns with the same input parameters:

```php
$key = '012345678901234567'; // 18 bytes key
$iv = "0123456789012345";    // 16 bytes IV
$plainText = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$cipherText = bin2hex(mcryptVal(pkcs5_pad($plainText), $key, $iv));
print($cipherText . PHP_EOL); // 4e4d648e1af730b6c7571cbd033a43c478f423a958f70bdf5929418e978d3126a7f7bbbeaea06e6cf12e99b922918917
```

the same ciphertext showing that both implementations are functionally equivalent